# React Redux fetching data from backend approach

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm a bit confused and would love an answer that will help me to clear my thoughts.
Let's say I have a backend (nodejs, express etc..) where I store my users and their data, and sometimes I wanna fetch data from the backend, such as the user info after he logs in, or a list of products and save them in the state.

My approach so far and what I've seen, I fetch the data before the component loads and dispatch an action with the data from the response.
But I recently started digging a bit about this and I saw react-thunk library which I knew earlier and started to wonder if what is the best practice of fetching from backend/API?
Has React Hooks change anything about this topic? Is it important to know this?

I feel a bit dumb but couldn't find an article or video that talks exactly about this topic :)

Comment: You can fetch in useEffect, use redux-thunk, redux-saga or redux-observable. Every option has some upsides and downsides and there is no clear winner. It all depends on the app you're building and your preferences. I personally prefer redux-saga because it's easy to test and the api is pleasant to work with. It's quite similar to thunk though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! is it important to know all of them and try them out? with hooks I do it inside useEffect as you mentioned but thats the only way I know and I feel a bit behind..

Comment: You can start with https://redux-toolkit.js.org/ that should be enough even for a complex project. You certainly don't have to know all of them. For simple apps hooks without redux will be enough. Currenlty there is even a trend in react community to to build apps using only context and hooks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do this best practice, use the following method:

I used some packages and patterns for best practice:

- [redux-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-logger) for log actions and states in console of browser.
- [reselect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reselect) Selectors can compute derived data, allowing Redux to
  store the minimal possible state and etc.
- [redux-thunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk) Thunks are the recommended middleware for basic
  Redux side effects logic, including complex synchronous logic that
  needs access to the store, and simple async logic like AJAX requests
  and etc.
- [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) for work with api (Promise based HTTP client for the
  browser and node.js)

> create a directory by name **redux** or any name of you like in **src folder** and
>   then create two files `store.js` and `rootReducer.js` in redux directory. We assume fetch products from API.

**To do this:**

> Create a new directory by name **product** in redux directory and then
>   create four files by names `product.types.js, product.actions.js,
>   product.reducer.js, product.selector.js` in `redux/product` directory

**The structure of the project should be as follows**

```
...
src
  App.js
  redux
    product
      product.types.js
      product.actions.js
      product.reducer.js
    rootReducer.js
    store.js
 Index.js
package.json
...
```

**store.js**

In this file we do the redux configuration

```
// redux/store.js:
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import logger from "redux-logger";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

import rootReducer from "./root-reducer";

const middlewares = [logger, thunk];

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
```

**rootReducer.js**

> The `combineReducers` helper function turns an object whose values are
>   different reducing functions into a single reducing function you can
>   pass to `createStore`.

```
// redux/rootReducer.js
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import productReducer from "./product/product.reducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  shop: productReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**product.types.js**
In this file we define constants for manage types of actions.

```
export const ShopActionTypes = {
  FETCH_PRODUCTS_START: "FETCH_PRODUCTS_START",
  FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS: "FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS",
  FETCH_PRODUCTS_FAILURE: "FETCH_PRODUCTS_FAILURE"
};
```

**product.actions.js**
In this file we create action creators for handle actions.

```
// redux/product/product.actions.js
import { ShopActionTypes } from "./product.types";
import axios from "axios";

export const fetchProductsStart = () => ({
  type: ShopActionTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_START
});

export const fetchProductsSuccess = products => ({
  type: ShopActionTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
  payload: products
});

export const fetchProductsFailure = error => ({
  type: ShopActionTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_FAILURE,
  payload: error
});

export const fetchProductsStartAsync = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchProductsStart());
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then(response => dispatch(fetchProductsSuccess(response.data.data)))
      .catch(error => dispatch(fetchProductsFailure(error)));
  };
};
```

**product.reducer.js**
In this file we create `productReducer` function for handle actions.

```
import { ShopActionTypes } from "./product.types";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  products: [],
  isFetching: false,
  errorMessage: undefined,
};

const productReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ShopActionTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_START:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true
      };
    case ShopActionTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        products: action.payload,
        isFetching: false
      };
    case ShopActionTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        errorMessage: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default productReducer;
```

**product.selector.js**
In this file we select `products` and `isFetching` from shop state.

```
import { createSelector } from "reselect";

const selectShop = state => state.shop;

export const selectProducts = createSelector(
  [selectShop],
  shop => shop.products
);

export const selectIsProductsFetching = createSelector(
  [selectShop],
  shop => shop.isFetching
);
```

**Index.js**
In this file wrapped whole app and components with `Provider` for access child components to the store and states.

```
// src/Index.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./redux/store";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**App.js class component**
In this file we do connect to the store and states with class component

```
// src/App.js
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { createStructuredSelector } from "reselect";
import {
  selectIsProductsFetching,
  selectProducts
} from "./redux/product/product.selectors";

import { fetchProductsStartAsync } from "./redux/product/product.actions";

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { fetchProductsStartAsync } = this.props;
    fetchProductsStartAsync();
  }

  render() {
    const { products, isProductsFetching } = this.props;
    console.log('products', products);
    console.log('isProductsFetching', isProductsFetching);
    return (
      <div className="App">Please see console in browser</div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  products: selectProducts,
  isProductsFetching: selectIsProductsFetching,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchProductsStartAsync: () => dispatch(fetchProductsStartAsync())
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

**or App.js with functional component ( useEffect hook )**
In this file we do connect to the store and states with functional component

```
// src/App.js
import React, { Component, useEffect } from "react";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { createStructuredSelector } from "reselect";
import {
  selectIsProductsFetching,
  selectProducts
} from "./redux/product/product.selectors";

import { fetchProductsStartAsync } from "./redux/product/product.actions";

const App = ({ fetchProductsStartAsync, products, isProductsFetching}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProductsStartAsync();
  },[]);

    console.log('products', products);
    console.log('isProductsFetching', isProductsFetching);

    return (
      <div className="App">Please see console in browser</div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  products: selectProducts,
  isProductsFetching: selectIsProductsFetching,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchProductsStartAsync: () => dispatch(fetchProductsStartAsync())
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

Comment: Thanks!! finally a complete example with explanations, it helped me a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome. If it helps, please check the green mark next to the voted. Good luck.