# Is Redux able to connect any state and action dispatch to any component?

Tags: reactjs, redux

This app is a simple Counter... does any one know how to make the App able to display the count also (beside the counter showing it)? Can you edit online and fork a copy if you can?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kkcgza?file=App.js

I can connect the "state and action" to the Counter component like below:

```
let connectedComponent = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Counter);

export default connectedComponent;
```

Do I just do the same for `App` as well? I don't quite understand the principle: is it that you first have a "one and only" source of truth (the redux store), and then you can arbitrarily connect any state and/or action dispatch to any component, so that any component can have any state and dispatch, and re-rendering is minimized?

So Redux is really a "data store, and props injector"?

Quote from Learning React, 2nd Ed, Kirupa Chinnathambi, Addison-Wesley 2018:

> You can initiate a state change and involve only the components that are impacted directly. This directness reduces a lot of overhead you would otherwise have to maintain to ensure that your data (and any changes to it) gets to its intended destination without causing unnecessary renders. Pretty cool, right?

Comment: If you make a sandbox (codesandbox.io) I can make an example

Comment: @DennisVash there is, it is on https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kkcgza?file=App.js and it seems using only 100MB instead of codesandbox.io 300MB or so (viewing by Chrome ➜ More Tools ➜ Task Manager)

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't connect the root component (which I assume is `<App>`) to the store but probably render another component that is connected. Assuming you have this structure:

```
<MyStoreProvider>
    <App>
        <SomeComponent>
            <CounterDisplay />
        </SomeComponent>
        <Counter />
    </App>
</MyStoreProvider>
```

where `CounterDisplay` is connected to your store:

```
const CounterDisplay = ({count}) => (
    <p>{`The count is ${count}`}</p>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({count: state.count});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CounterDisplay);
```

Usually you would try to keep the connect as close as possible to the components that actually need state or actions to prevent re-rendering the whole tree and reducing the need to pass state down.

It's even easier to use with [hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#hooks):

```
const CounterDisplay = () => {
    const count = useSelector(state => state.count);

    return (
        <p>{`The count is ${count}`}</p>
    );
};
```

> So Redux is really a "data store, and props injector"?

You could call it that. It's a state management library that allows you to subscribe to state changes and update state in a non-mutating comprehensible manner (to e.g. allow time-traveling through your state changes). It can actually be used completely without react. The actual bindings that allow it to be used conveniently with react are in a standalone `react-redux` package.

Comment: are you saying you could connect the `state.count` to `App` as `props.countFooBar` but you just wouldn't (because it can cause the whole `App` and subtree to re-render)?

Comment: @nonopolarity exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
import React from "react";
import Counter from "./Counter";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

function App(props) {
  console.log("APP is re-rendering", props);

  return (
   <div>
    App Cunter: {props.countValue}
    <br/>
    App says hello
    <Counter />
   </div>
  );
}


export default connect( state => ({countValue: state.count}))(App)
```

You only need to connect App component that way to achieve what you want

Comment: I used to think those `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps` make me dizzy... so it is actually quite simple `connect( state => ({countValue: state.count}))(App)` and the idea is to make those available to the component as props

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you. You can, however, use the *useSelector* function hook from react-redux, it is cleaner

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) for select states for example `countValue` with best practice and performance and then for more information see link below

> You can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60310092/12462892) for best practice work with react and redux

Comment: Generally speaking this is correct but in the particular example there aren't really any criteria to filter for as the count is just a plain number.

Comment: **Selectors are efficient. A selector is not recomputed unless one of its arguments changes.**. This is an advantage no matter whether the program is simple or complex

Comment: I understand that but what would be the arguments in case of a simple count? A selector is only useful if you have some criteria that your selected state depends on.

Comment: If you want to look at it like that. You can do this with a Context-Api without using a redux

Comment: I agree you wouldn't even need redux for a simple counter app and instead just use the react context API which in fact is what react-redux also uses. But that is unrelated to whether or not you need selectors. A selector is also not tied to redux in any way.

Comment: I like to talk about this. Because both you and me can give information. the dude

Comment: I appreciate your mention of `reselect`. It's a useful library.

Comment: Yes that's right. But my goal is always to develop what programs, small and large, meet standards and optimize them, because development will be easier in the future.