# Where in redux to call a function that writes data from payload?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Where in redux to call a function that writes data to a new user?

There is a function addDataUser (), it writes data to the database, in which place to call it to pass data from payload to it?

Services.js // Add data user

```
  addDataUsers = user => {
    firebase.firestore()
     .collection("users")
     .add({
       user: user
     });
  };
```

authActions.js // Actions

```
const userSignup = user => {
    return {
        type: "FETCH_USER_SIGNUP",
        payload: user
    };
};
```

authReducer.js // Reducer

```
const initialState = {
    userToken: []
};

const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "FETCH_USER_SIGNUP":
        return {
            ...state,
            userToken: {
            ...state.userToken,
            user: action.payload.login,
            userToken: Math.random() + action.payload.login
           }
         };
    default: return state;
   };
 };
```

The user clicks "Registration" and all the data from the form is sent to authActions, but how and where to call the addDatauser (PAYLOAD) function to give it action.payload?

Comment: You can do it in action, Use redux-thunk to hold your dispatch. Read in detail about redux-thunk you will come to know, where should you place the call.

Answer (score 1):

you should be use async action middleware like:

[redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)

[redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/)

for example we use redux-thunk:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const addDataUser = user => ({
  type: "FETCH_USER_SIGNUP",
  payload: user
});

export const addDataUserAsync = () => dispatch => {
  axios.post(url)
  .then(response => dispatch(addDataUser(response)))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

then access to payload in reducer.

**Maybe it will help you and for more information I answered this question in full:**

[React Redux fetching data from backend approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60308343/react-redux-fetching-data-from-backend-approach/60310092#60310092)

Answer (score 0):

After you call `addDataUsers` you can "dispatch" the data using your `userSignup` action.

If you use [redux hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks), it would be something like:

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
// import your functions

export const YourComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const onRegistrationClick = useCallback(async () => {
    // This function is called when registration button is pressed
    const data = /* your data logic */
    const docRef = await addDataUsers(data)
    const userDoc = await db.collection('users').doc(docRef.id).get()
    const user = userDoc.data()
    // --> HERE you "save" the data to your store <--
    dispatch(userSignUp(user))
  }, [dispatch])
  // ...
}
```

Another alternative is to use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) and add all the logic in a single action:

```
function addUserAndStore(data) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const docRef = await addDataUsers(data)
    const userDoc = await db.collection('users').doc(docRef.id).get()
    const user = userDoc.data()
    // --> HERE you "save" the data to your store <--
    dispatch(userSignUp(user))
  }
}
```

Then in your component code you only have to call it:

```
dispatch(addUserAndStore(data))
```