# API works in postman but not in react front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-redux

I am trying to make an app with the MERN Stack and have run into an issue. My app allows a "create profile" and "edit profile" component that uses the same API route since its a post request that has very similar actions. When I try to create a profile, everything works fine, but when I try to edit the profile I am running into an error. First of all, when I click the submit button (that calls the axios.post() route from the edit profile) the redux types don't show up, and in 2 mins the application crashes. Secondly, it works fine in postman.

Here is the code in question

profile action

```
//create or update a profile

export const createProfile = (
  formData,
  history,
  edit = false
) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    };

    const res = await axios.post("/api/profile", formData, config);

    dispatch({ type: GET_PROFILE, payload: res.data });
    dispatch(setAlert(edit ? "Profile Updated" : "Profile Created", "success"));

    if (!edit) {
      history.push("/dashboard");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    //const errors = err.response.data.errors;

    if (err.response) {
      //errors.forEach(error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, "danger")));
      dispatch(setAlert("response error", "danger"));
    } else if (err.request) {
      console.log(err.request);
      //dispatch(setAlert("req error", "danger"));
    } else {
      dispatch(setAlert("another error", "danger"));
    }

    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
    });
  }
};
```

API route

```
// @route    POST api/profile
// @desc     create or update a profile
// @access   Public

router.post(
  "/",
  [
    auth,
    [
      check("status", "Status is required")
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check("skills", "Skills is required")
        .not()
        .isEmpty()
    ]
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    const {
      company,
      website,
      bio,
      location,
      skills,
      status,
      githubusername,
      youtube,
      facebook,
      twitter,
      linkedin,
      instagram
    } = req.body;

    const profileFields = {};
    profileFields.user = req.user.id;

    if (company) profileFields.company = company;
    if (website) profileFields.website = website;
    if (bio) profileFields.bio = bio;
    if (location) profileFields.location = location;
    if (skills) {
      profileFields.skills = skills.split(",").map(skill => skill.trim());
    }
    if (status) profileFields.status = status;
    if (githubusername) profileFields.githubusername = githubusername;

    profileFields.social = {};
    if (youtube) profileFields.social.youtube = youtube;
    if (facebook) profileFields.social.facebook = facebook;
    if (twitter) profileFields.social.twitter = twitter;
    if (linkedin) profileFields.social.linkedin = linkedin;
    if (instagram) profileFields.social.instagram = instagram;

    try {
      let profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id });

      if (profile) {
        //update
        profile = await Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
          { user: req.user.id },
          { $set: profileFields },
          { new: true }
        );

        return res.json(profile);
      }

      //create

      profile = new Profile(profileFields);
      await profile.save();
      return res.json(profile);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send("Server Error");
    }
  }
);
```

front end component this issue arises in

```
import React, { useState, Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { createProfile, getCurrentProfile } from "../../actions/profile";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const EditProfile = ({
  profile: { profile, loading },
  createProfile,
  getCurrentProfile,
  history
}) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    company: "",
    website: "",
    location: "",
    status: "",
    skills: "",
    githubusername: "",
    bio: "",
    twitter: "",
    facebook: "",
    instagram: "",
    linkedin: "",
    youtube: ""
  });

  const [displaySocialInputs, toggleSocialInputs] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentProfile();

    setFormData({
      company: loading || !profile.company ? "" : profile.company,
      website: loading || !profile.website ? "" : profile.website,
      location: loading || !profile.location ? "" : profile.location,
      status: loading || !profile.status ? "" : profile.status,
      skills: loading || !profile.skills ? "" : profile.skills,
      githubusername:
        loading || !profile.githubusername ? "" : profile.githubusername,
      bio: loading || !profile.bio ? "" : profile.bio,
      twitter: loading || !profile.social ? "" : profile.social.twitter,
      facebook: loading || !profile.social ? "" : profile.social.facebook,
      instagram: loading || !profile.social ? "" : profile.social.instagram,
      linkedin: loading || !profile.social ? "" : profile.social.linkedin,
      youtube: loading || !profile.social ? "" : profile.social.youtube
    });
  }, [loading, getCurrentProfile]);

  const {
    company,
    website,
    location,
    status,
    skills,
    githubusername,
    bio,
    twitter,
    facebook,
    instagram,
    linkedin,
    youtube
  } = formData;

  const onChange = e =>
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    createProfile(formData, history);
    console.log("updating");
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className='large text-primary'>Edit Your Profile</h1>
      <p className='lead'>
        <i className='fas fa-user'></i> Let's get some information to make your
        profile stand out
      </p>
      <small>* = required field</small>
      <form className='form' onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <select name='status' value={status} onChange={e => onChange(e)}>
            <option value='0'>* Select Professional Status</option>
            <option value='Developer'>Developer</option>
            <option value='Junior Developer'>Junior Developer</option>
            <option value='Senior Developer'>Senior Developer</option>
            <option value='Manager'>Manager</option>
            <option value='Student or Learning'>Student or Learning</option>
            <option value='Instructor'>Instructor or Teacher</option>
            <option value='Intern'>Intern</option>
            <option value='Other'>Other</option>
          </select>
          <small className='form-text'>
            Give us an idea of where you are at in your career
          </small>
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='Company'
            name='company'
            value={company}
            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
          />
          <small className='form-text'>
            Could be your own company or one you work for
          </small>
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='Website'
            name='website'
            value={website}
            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
          />
          <small className='form-text'>
            Could be your own or a company website
          </small>
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='Location'
            name='location'
            value={location}
            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
          />
          <small className='form-text'>
            City & state suggested (eg. Boston, MA)
          </small>
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='* Skills'
            name='skills'
            value={skills}
            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
          />
          <small className='form-text'>
            Please use comma separated values (eg. HTML,CSS,JavaScript,PHP)
          </small>
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='Github Username'
            name='githubusername'
            value={githubusername}
            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
          />
          <small className='form-text'>
            If you want your latest repos and a Github link, include your
            username
          </small>
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <textarea
            placeholder='A short bio of yourself'
            name='bio'
            value={bio}
            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
          ></textarea>
          <small className='form-text'>Tell us a little about yourself</small>
        </div>

        <div className='my-2'>
          <button
            type='button'
            className='btn btn-light'
            onClick={() => toggleSocialInputs(!displaySocialInputs)}
          >
            Add Social Network Links
          </button>
          <span>Optional</span>
        </div>
        {displaySocialInputs && (
          <Fragment>
            <div className='form-group social-input'>
              <i className='fab fa-twitter fa-2x'></i>
              <input
                type='text'
                placeholder='Twitter URL'
                name='twitter'
                value={twitter}
                onChange={e => onChange(e)}
              />
            </div>

            <div className='form-group social-input'>
              <i className='fab fa-facebook fa-2x'></i>
              <input
                type='text'
                placeholder='Facebook URL'
                name='facebook'
                value={facebook}
                onChange={e => onChange(e)}
              />
            </div>

            <div className='form-group social-input'>
              <i className='fab fa-youtube fa-2x'></i>
              <input
                type='text'
                placeholder='YouTube URL'
                name='youtube'
                value={youtube}
                onChange={e => onChange(e)}
              />
            </div>

            <div className='form-group social-input'>
              <i className='fab fa-linkedin fa-2x'></i>
              <input
                type='text'
                placeholder='Linkedin URL'
                name='linkedin'
                value={linkedin}
                onChange={e => onChange(e)}
              />
            </div>

            <div className='form-group social-input'>
              <i className='fab fa-instagram fa-2x'></i>
              <input
                type='text'
                placeholder='Instagram URL'
                name='instagram'
                value={instagram}
                onChange={e => onChange(e)}
              />
            </div>
          </Fragment>
        )}
        <input type='submit' className='btn btn-primary my-1' />
        <Link className='btn btn-light my-1' to='/dashboard'>
          Go Back
        </Link>
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

EditProfile.propTypes = {
  createProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  getCurrentProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  profile: state.profile
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { createProfile, getCurrentProfile })(
  withRouter(EditProfile)
);
```

here is the errors I get in the console after it stalls and crashes

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/profile net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I've opened the networks tab and when I clicked on the response error, it said "failed to load response data" so not even that worked

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**Check out the steps below: (It may help)**

**First-step:**

You must use the redux async action middleware like([redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk), [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/)) to handle the api requests.

**Second-step:**

When you use the axios for handle the api requests, check the **headers** like(Authorization, ...) and **data** that you pass correctly:

**Example**

```
axios.post('/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  },{
  headers:{
    Accept: 'application/json',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token // if you use token
}
})
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

**Third-step:**

> For better understanding you can see this question: [React Redux
>   fetching data from backend approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60310092/12462892)

Answer (score -5):

Try this it may help, its working fine for me.

```
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('email', 'test@gmail.com');
formData.append('password', '123456');

fetch("https://test.com/api/login", {
    method: 'post',
    body: formData
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(
(result) => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})
```