# is there a way to call another action from one action in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-redux

I have two action in my redux actions... now I have a login form that makes a post request.. now I want to call another action from within the login action.
Now i connected the login function but not the setLoading function

e.g

```
export const loginUser = ()=>dispatch=>{
 setLoading();
}

export const setLoading = ()=>({
type: SET_LOADING
})
```

Comment: redux-thunk is what you are looking for

Comment: You can dispatch an action after that you resolve it in the used milddleware in your project. an action is a plain object, the code you provided are action creators

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logic of this answer to help you. An example is given in this answer(That's an example of getting products).

[React Redux fetching data from backend approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60308343/react-redux-fetching-data-from-backend-approach/60310092#60310092)

> For your problem, it's best to pay attention to this part of the link
>   I gave you above, since you can use that logic for your program.

**Notice this in the link above**

```
// redux/product/product.actions.js
import { ShopActionTypes } from "./product.types";
import axios from "axios";

export const fetchProductsStart = () => ({
  type: ShopActionTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_START
});

export const fetchProductsSuccess = products => ({
  type: ShopActionTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
  payload: products
});

export const fetchProductsFailure = error => ({
  type: ShopActionTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_FAILURE,
  payload: error
});

export const fetchProductsStartAsync = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchProductsStart());
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then(response => dispatch(fetchProductsSuccess(response.data.data)))
      .catch(error => dispatch(fetchProductsFailure(error)));
  };
};
```

Comment: But My problems is not like that... I have another function that takes in dispatch and calls that dispatch...